# Does Freeswitch plays .AMR files?

Tags: codec, freeswitch, amr

I want to play .amr files in freeswitch IVR.Is that possible?

While checking freeswitch forums,i found out AMR is only for passthru mode.What is a passthru mode?

Is there any way to over come this and play the AMR file in freeswitch?

Any suggestions please.

```
06e95939-04bc-4c9c-9b01-e955ddeefa00 2021-03-09 11:26:24.086462 [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:898 Local SDP sofia/internal/1000@192.168.151.144:5070:
06e95939-04bc-4c9c-9b01-e955ddeefa00 v=0^M
06e95939-04bc-4c9c-9b01-e955ddeefa00 o=FreeSWITCH 1615239368 1615239369 IN IP4 192.168.151.144^M
06e95939-04bc-4c9c-9b01-e955ddeefa00 s=FreeSWITCH^M
06e95939-04bc-4c9c-9b01-e955ddeefa00 c=IN IP4 192.168.151.144^M
06e95939-04bc-4c9c-9b01-e955ddeefa00 t=0 0^M
06e95939-04bc-4c9c-9b01-e955ddeefa00 m=audio 30016 RTP/AVP 0 101^M
06e95939-04bc-4c9c-9b01-e955ddeefa00 a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000^M
06e95939-04bc-4c9c-9b01-e955ddeefa00 a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000^M
06e95939-04bc-4c9c-9b01-e955ddeefa00 a=fmtp:101 0-16^M
06e95939-04bc-4c9c-9b01-e955ddeefa00 a=ptime:20^M
06e95939-04bc-4c9c-9b01-e955ddeefa00 a=sendrecv^M
06e95939-04bc-4c9c-9b01-e955ddeefa00
06e95939-04bc-4c9c-9b01-e955ddeefa00 2021-03-09 11:26:24.086462 [NOTICE] mod_dptools.c:1406 Channel [sofia/internal/1000@192.168.151.144:5070] has been answere
d
06e95939-04bc-4c9c-9b01-e955ddeefa00 2021-03-09 11:26:24.086462 [DEBUG] switch_channel.c:3865 (sofia/internal/1000@192.168.151.144:5070) Callstate Change EARLY
 -> ACTIVE
06e95939-04bc-4c9c-9b01-e955ddeefa00 2021-03-09 11:26:24.086462 [DEBUG] sofia.c:7325 Channel sofia/internal/1000@192.168.151.144:5070 entering state [completed
][200]
06e95939-04bc-4c9c-9b01-e955ddeefa00 EXECUTE [depth=0] sofia/internal/1000@192.168.151.144:5070 sleep(1500)
06e95939-04bc-4c9c-9b01-e955ddeefa00 2021-03-09 11:26:24.166466 [DEBUG] switch_rtp.c:7722 Correct audio ip/port confirmed.
06e95939-04bc-4c9c-9b01-e955ddeefa00 2021-03-09 11:26:24.326464 [DEBUG] sofia.c:7325 Channel sofia/internal/1000@192.168.151.144:5070 entering state [ready][20
0]
06e95939-04bc-4c9c-9b01-e955ddeefa00 EXECUTE [depth=0] sofia/internal/1000@192.168.151.144:5070 playback(phrase:AMR_TESTING)
06e95939-04bc-4c9c-9b01-e955ddeefa00 2021-03-09 11:26:25.606464 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_play_say.c:70 No language specified - Using [en]
06e95939-04bc-4c9c-9b01-e955ddeefa00 2021-03-09 11:26:25.626462 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_play_say.c:250 Handle play-file:[ivr/ivr-record-prompt.AMR] (en:en)
2021-03-09 11:26:25.626462 [ERR] switch_core_file.c:307 Invalid file format [AMR] for [/usr/local/freeswitch/sounds/en/us/callie/ivr/ivr-record-prompt.AMR]!
06e95939-04bc-4c9c-9b01-e955ddeefa00 EXECUTE [depth=0] sofia/internal/1000@192.168.151.144:5070 hangup()
06e95939-04bc-4c9c-9b01-e955ddeefa00 2021-03-09 11:26:26.386463 [NOTICE] mod_dptools.c:1380 Hangup sofia/internal/1000@192.168.151.144:5070 [CS_EXECUTE] [NORMA
L_CLEARING]
06e95939-04bc-4c9c-9b01-e955ddeefa00 2021-03-09 11:26:26.386463 [DEBUG] switch_core_session.c:2905 sofia/internal/1000@192.168.151.144:5070 skip receive messag
e [APPLICATION_EXEC_COMPLETE] (channel is hungup already)
06e95939-04bc-4c9c-9b01-e955ddeefa00 2021-03-09 11:26:26.386463 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:651 (sofia/internal/1000@192.168.151.144:5070) State EXECUT
E going to sleep
06e95939-04bc-4c9c-9b01-e955ddeefa00 2021-03-09 11:26:26.386463 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:585 (sofia/internal/1000@192.168.151.144:5070) Running Stat
e Change CS_HANGUP (Cur 1 Tot 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

No, according to the source code, there is no module supports file with extension ".amr"